# Bluetooth manager requests use of pin to pair headphones - elementaryOS

Tags: bluetooth

Problem: When I try to connect my logitech bluetooth headphones, the headphones are recognized, however, the bluetooth manager than provides a pin code asks me to input it to headphones...???  There is no input on my headphones. They are recognized as headphone/audio. 
Latest download available from ElementaryOS as of May
Thinkpad X61
Logitek H600 headphones

Only options offered by ElementaryOS are to Input Pin on headphones, or cancel.

Comment: Just press accept. It should work.  To connect my BT headphones I just turn them on, then I click on + on the BT settings page and then just press on the headphones. That way It pairs them automatically.

Comment: As stated, the only options offered are the pin number, and a "cancel" button... There is no "accept" button. Presumably, once the pin number has been entered on the device aide, bluetooth manager would then simply connect.

Comment: It worked! My device was listed but was toggling (connected disconnected). I first removed the device by running > remove *Mac address* and then followed the instructions above. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I would just use terminal to pair with the headset if the bluetooth manager is causing problems

```
bluetoothctl
scan on
```

If the headset is in pairing mode it should show as a `[NEW] Device` followed by the MAC address and it's bluetooth name
Then just do

`pair` followed by the MAC address- use capital letters

`trust` followed by the MAC and then use `connect` followed by the MAC and finally you can quit `bluetoothctl` with the `quit` command.

As an example, I have a device that reports as `[NEW] Device E8:07:BF:05:7D:BA iHome iBT60`

So I would

```
pair E8:07:BF:05:7D:BA
trust E8:07:BF:05:7D:BA
connect E8:07:BF:05:7D:BA
quit
```

The terminal will give you feedback as the whether each command is successful.  If the device doesn't show in Sound Settings after this check

```
pactl list short | grep blue
```

See if module-bluetooth-discover is loaded, if not

```
pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover
```

Then connect to the device and it should appear in Sound Settings

`

Comment: That worked. Got them working. Guess I'll make a little shell script and a bash alias to run it...  Learn something new everyday..  (should I report this as a bug somewhere?).

Comment: You shouldn't need to run the bluetoothctl commands again unless you pair the headphones with something else and you could see if the blueman bluetooth manager works better than the default one

Comment: Geez... better than Bluez/Bluetooth-Manager... just automatically re-connects from session to session. Thanks

Comment: If you are happy with the answer, click on the check mark to accept it