# Bluetooth not work on elementary os 0.4 Loki

Tags: bluetooth

I've installed elementary OS on my laptop but bluetooth doesn't recognize any device, can someone help me? I'm not expert with the ubuntu system...and sorry for my english

```
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 0a)
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [17aa:3830]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
    Subsystem: XAVi Technologies Corp. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [1b9a:2485]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be
    Kernel modules: rtl8723be, wl



Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f2:b49f Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 174f:1169 Syntek 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 062a:4102 Creative Labs 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub



0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
4: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

    [    0.160519] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    0.364113] acpi PNP0A08:00: [Firmware Info]: MMCONFIG for domain 0000 [bus 00-3f] only partially covers this bridge
[    1.466117] [Firmware Bug]: No valid trip found
[    2.610072] usb 1-4: Product: Bluetooth Radio 
[   10.398181] rtl8723be: Using firmware rtlwifi/rtl8723befw.bin
[   11.842460] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.21
[   11.842487] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   11.842493] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   11.842498] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   11.842508] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   12.626712] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: examining hci_ver=06 hci_rev=000b lmp_ver=06 lmp_subver=8723
[   12.626719] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723b_fw.bin
[   12.698802] Bluetooth: hci0: rom_version status=0 version=1
[   17.016934] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   17.016940] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   17.016947] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   19.079058] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x0c56 tx timeout
[   38.328458] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   38.328470] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   38.328483] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[ 1171.588454] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: examining hci_ver=06 hci_rev=000b lmp_ver=06 lmp_subver=8723
[ 1171.588462] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723b_fw.bin
[ 1171.589660] Bluetooth: hci0: rom_version status=0 version=1
[ 3599.475358] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: examining hci_ver=06 hci_rev=000b lmp_ver=06 lmp_subver=8723
[ 3599.475364] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723b_fw.bin
[ 3599.476353] Bluetooth: hci0: rom_version status=0 version=1
```

Results from `dmesg | grep 'usb 1-4'`

```
[ 2.432072] usb 1-4: new full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd 
[ 2.561475] usb 1-4: New USB device found, idVendor=04f2, idProduct=b49f 
[ 2.561481] usb 1-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3 
[ 2.561484] usb 1-4: Product: Bluetooth Radio 
[ 2.561487] usb 1-4: Manufacturer: Realtek 
[ 2.561489] usb 1-4: SerialNumber: 00e04c000001 
[16443.840076] usb 1-4: reset full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd 
[41178.579274] usb 1-4: reset full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
```

Comment: Please edit the question to include results from terminal for `lspci -nnk |grep -iA3 net; lsusb; rfkill list; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'` Thanks

Comment: okay, i did it.

Comment: How about adding results for `dmesg | grep 'usb 1-4'`

Comment: [    2.432072] usb 1-4: new full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[    2.561475] usb 1-4: New USB device found, idVendor=04f2, idProduct=b49f
[    2.561481] usb 1-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[    2.561484] usb 1-4: Product: Bluetooth Radio 
[    2.561487] usb 1-4: Manufacturer: Realtek 
[    2.561489] usb 1-4: SerialNumber: 00e04c000001
[16443.840076] usb 1-4: reset full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[41178.579274] usb 1-4: reset full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd

Answer (score 4):

maybe your bluetooth is soft blocked? try :

```
sudo rfkill list
```

if it is blocked, try this command

```
sudo rfkill unblock bluetooth
```

hope it helps!

Comment: it isn't blocked :(

Comment: Worked for me :)

Answer (score 1):

I think I have a solution.

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic git build-essential
git clone https://github.com/jeremyb31/bluetooth-4.4.git
cd bluetooth-4.4
cp /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/.config ./
cp /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/Module.symvers Module.symvers
make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$(pwd) modules
sudo cp btusb.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/
sudo modprobe -r btusb
sudo modprobe btusb
```

It should work but it will have to be compiled again for new kernels, when a new kernel is installed bluetooth will not function until you

```
cd bluetooth-4.4
make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$(pwd) clean
cp /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/.config ./
cp /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/Module.symvers Module.symvers
make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$(pwd) modules
sudo cp btusb.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/
sudo modprobe -r btusb
sudo modprobe btusb
```

Comment: Now the smartphone recognize the pc but te pc still doesn't find any device...i've tried to connect the smartphone to the pc but doesn't work

Comment: Try in terminal `bluetoothctl` then `power on`, `scan on` and see if it finds the phone and it might help to reboot

Comment: It says "discovery started" but it doesn't find anything

Comment: Please edit your question to include new results for `dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'` so I can see if it is loading the firmware

Comment: okay, i did it.

Comment: I cannot help further as I don't know what is causing the problem.  I would file a bug report at https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+filebug  I would file against package linux as your bluetooth isn't correctly supported in any kernel at this time.  I actually made a [patch](https://github.com/jeremyb31/bluetooth-4.4/commit/20d1eb299795fd55765f02d94154d1d63381da27) to get the firmware to load

Comment: Maybe explain what you're doing here and why? Isn't updating the kernel easier? Especially with graphical programs like Ukuu.

Comment: My github source code provides some support for this bluetooth device that isn't in the newest kernel at kernel.org

Answer (score 0):

I was having difficulty with bluetooth as well and the solution offered up worked, AND it seems to have cured the graphical bluetooth manager too... Here is the link to the thread [Bluetooth manager requests use of pin to pair headphones - elementaryOS](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/12027/bluetooth-manager-requests-use-of-pin-to-pair-headphones-elementaryos/12041?noredirect=1#comment15329_12041)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have tlp installed? Try removing it or blocking the bluetooth device:
https://forum.manjaro.org/t/bluetooth-adapter-cannot-be-turned-on-realtek-rtl8723be/10130/32

Do you have powertop installed?
Check if you set something like: