# Problems connecting to blutooth speaker

Tags: release-loki, bluetooth

First, bluetooth device search didn't find my speaker, so I followed [this](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/12027/bluetooth-manager-requests-use-of-pin-to-pair-headphones-elementaryos/12041?noredirect=1#comment15329_12041) post. Using `bluetoothctl` I could pair, connect, and trust my speaker and clicking on the bluetooth icon shows my speaker, however it still doesn't show up in device search.

After connecting via `bluetoothctl` it worked at first, but when I connect now either via the bluetooth icon or the command line it says it is connected, but it isn't really, since the speaker doesn't appear in sound settings and the audio continues to be played over my laptop speakers. It disconnects and connects regularly. The output is the following:

```
sudo bluetoothctl -a
[NEW] Controller 34:DE:1A:4D:1F:8D loki [default]
[NEW] Device 00:E0:4C:43:F2:51 SoundCore mini
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# connect 00:E0:4C:43:F2:51
Attempting to connect to 00:E0:4C:43:F2:51
[CHG] Device 00:E0:4C:43:F2:51 Connected: yes
Connection successful
[CHG] Device 00:E0:4C:43:F2:51 Connected: no
[CHG] Device 00:E0:4C:43:F2:51 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device 00:E0:4C:43:F2:51 Connected: no
[CHG] Device 00:E0:4C:43:F2:51 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device 00:E0:4C:43:F2:51 Connected: no
```

and so on.. I followed the instructions in [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/258074/error-when-trying-to-connect-to-bluetooth-speaker-org-bluez-error-failed) post as well, but `pulseaudio-module-bluetooth` is installed and killing and restarting pulseaudio didn't solve the problem. module-bluetooth-discover is loaded:

```
pactl list short | grep blue
8   module-bluetooth-policy     
9   module-bluetooth-discover       
10  module-bluez5-discover
```

Trying to load the module results in the following error, but I guess that's irrelevant, since it's loaded already:

```
sudo pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover
Home directory not accessible: Permission denied
Connection failure: Connection refused
pa_context_connect() failed: Connection refused
```

Does anyone have an idea why it first worked and then not anymore? Could it have anything to do with the fact that after it first worked I connected my phone to the speaker? It isn't connected anymore, of course. Thanks for any help.

By the way, I just tried to connect another bluetooth speaker and it worked, with the speaker showing up in device search as well. I don't think that there is any problem with the other speaker though, I've never had problems connecting to it with different phones or windows computers.

Comment: anyone? the problem persists, I cannot connect to that speaker anymore, it says connected, but doesn't appear in sound settings and disconnects all the time

Comment: Does this OS ever work for bluetooth Audio?

Comment: Yes, I could connect another Bluetooth speaker, as well as my phone

Comment: I have a very similar issue with trying to pair with an Anker SoundCoreMini on Loki.  I went through the same steps as you, and I also could not load the `module-bluetooth-discover`, although I got a `Module initialization failed` message.  Did u ever resolve this issue?

Comment: Hi @JamesAdamCampbell, in fact I was using the exact same speaker. Unfortunately no, I never got it resolved. Let me know if you have any success.

Comment: Am also waiting for the answer in 2020